# Reveal.js does not load in ios9.3

Tags: reveal.js, ios9.3

My old iPad (ios9.3) refuses to load any reveal.js slides. It only shows the "Fork me on Github" image on the top corner. I suppose it will be that ios 9.3 does not support some new features of html5+js+css (I am not a developer, my skills are quite limited, so please excuse me if I say something stupid).

I am very interested in using it on an iPad due to the chalkboard plugin.

Any of you know what can be causing the trouble? Could I disable any of these features/files and make it work?

Thank you.

aimar

Comment: Surfing on the net, I found that some reveal.js do load properly on the iPad, e.g. [this site](http://courses.telematique.eu/reveal.js-plugins/chalkboard-demo.html#/). Although I do not know why. I will follow searching ...

Comment: Some demos of the plugin site do load in iOS 9.3 and some do not. I wonder if some are created upon older versions of reveal.js, because I see that their main HTML file presents different ways of initializing the plugins and the folder/files structure is also different. I guess this will be a patchwork task, trial and error, until I find which version/plugin couples with each other. A long journey ...

Comment: So far, using reveal.js in its v3, I am able to visualize the presentation in iOS9.3. However, when I add chalkboard plugin it does not show anything. And this plugin is the main reason to switch to reveal.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During all this weekend I was trying to figure out a solution. Finally, I manage to debug iOS safari from my windows laptop following [this](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) procedure and found that an "Unexpected identifier" was impeding "chalkboard" plugin to load.

A variable was defined with "let" command that, as I learnt, was not recognized by safari 9. I changed 4 "let"s with 4 "var"s commands in "plugin.js" (chalkboard plugin) and now it works in my old iPad, even with reveal v4.

Now I have another issue with the menus (menu plugin) not showing properly, but I will try also to fix it.